# Where is $f(x + y i) = x^2-y^2$ complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

The function $f$ is defined on the complex numbers by $f(x + y i) = x^2 - y^2$, where $x$ and $y$ are the real and imaginary parts of the parameter.

Our class's notes say that $f$ is complex differentiable along the line $y=-x$, but I keep getting by Cauchy Riemann equation that the origin is the only possible point. Am I missing something here? $f_x = 2x$ and $f_y = -2y$ so by $f_x= -i*f_y$ only when $x = 0 = y$...

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are real or complex variables? $f$ is real-valued or complex-valued? Is that the real part of $f$ and there's an imaginary part you didn't specify? The question, as written, is unclear.

Comment: Am I right in saying that f_x is $f_x$

Comment: Yes to Bruce.  To Alon, x and y are real, where z = x+yi is the composite complex argument.

Comment: @MathGuyForLife do add these facts to the question details to improve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are right and by Cauchy-Riemann equations, the origin is the only possible point that the function $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ is differentiable. Indeed $$u_x=2x=v_y=0=v_x=-u_y=2y$$

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that what your notes say is that if $f(x+yi)=x^2-y^2i$, then the points of $\mathbb C$ at which $f$ is diferentiable are those of the form $x-xi$ (and only those). This follows indeed from the Cauchy-Riemann equations, since, in this case, $u(x,y)=x^2$ and $v(x,y)=-y^2$.